# Date comparison in Struts2 Ognl tags

Tags: java, jsp, date, struts2, ognl

My requirement is to display a date from db and the status message to inform whether the date coming from db is past date, current date or a future date.

I'm displaying the date from db by

```
<s:property value="%{selObj.lastdate}"/>
```

Now how to get the current date in OGNL tags, I have tried

```
<s:propery value="%{new Date()}"/>
```

I need this current date to compare with selObj.lastdate and find out the date is passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`If you can modify your action side:`

You can try to write a getter as like:

```
public Date getCurrentDate(){
    return new Date();
}
```

at your Java(Action) side.

So you can get that value:

```
<s:property value="currentDate"/>
```

at your JSP side.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current date/time, you won't need to modify your action class, just add this line to your jsp:

```
<s:property value="@java.util.Calendar@getInstance().time" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's is the right way to compare and get current date. I have to suggest to display a date in UI, should use like this;

```
<s:date name="currentDate"  format="dd-MM-yyyy" />
```

It will be formatted date.